# Pyotherside for Ubuntu Touch Mendeley App

Tags: ubuntu-touch, python, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am an owner of both the BQ M10 Ubuntu Tablet and the BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Phone and I am very unhappy with the absence of a Mendeley app for these devices. For this reason, I want to code it myself using the Mendeley Python SDK.

I want to do this using QML together with Pyotherside. Unfortunately, I do not know yet how to bundle Pyotherside with my app using the Ubuntu SDK. I found [this](https://github.com/Sturmflut/ubuntu-touch-pyotherside-template) template, which I could use as a starting point but I would like to understand how I can do this myself.

Another question concerns the use of the mendeley library within a QML/Pyotherside app. Is there a way to deliver this library together with the app or will people need to install this library by themselves in order to use my app.

Summarizing, I have two questions:

1) How to set up Pyotherside for my Ubuntu Touch app?

2) How to include arbitrary python libraries in my app?

I would be very grateful for your help.

Best regards,
Sven